# Rails4 update.js.erb get content has error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I used Rails4. And now , I want to get the comment content in the `update.js.erb`, But it through out this error : **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**.

**My `comments_controller.rb`**

```
def update
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**My comment content in mysql is like this :**
[image]

**I use `editor.md` to save the comment content. And the setting is like this :**

```
c_md = editormd(e, {
                    autoHeight: true,
                    path    : "/editormd/lib/",
                    watch : false,
                    toolbar :false,
                    saveHTMLToTextarea : true,
                    placeholder: "",
                    imageUpload    : true,
                    imageFormats   : ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "bmp", "webp"],
                    imageUploadURL : "public/qImages"
                });
```

**My `update.js.erb` just like this:**

```
alert(<%= @comment.content %>)
```

when I update the comment, the terminal dispaly that I had correctly updated the content.just like this:

[image]

**But I could not get the right result in Chrome. The error is like this:**

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

This is for why? Anyone help me ? Thanks so much .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the [escape_javascript](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) helper:

```
alert("<%= j @comment.content %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"` when alert due to the value type is string and also replace the special characters such as `\r\n` in `ruby` side

```
alert("<%= @comment.content %>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @lucumt, But when I add `"` to it ,It doesn't work, and also has 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' error. Is there any methods to solve this problem?

Comment: @SylorHuang the return value contains some special characters,such as `\r\n`,which makes the `comment.content` value to a special string, you need to escape them in `ruby` side

Comment: But `<%= @comment.content %>` works good in `*.html.erb`, and if I remove the `\r\n` , will it influential when the content  markdown  to html ? Any way ,I will try to remove the `\r\n`. @lucumt ,Thanks so much .

Comment: I used `alert("<%= @comment.content %>".gsub("\r\n", ''))` to remove the `\r\n`, is that right? I also get the same error.

Comment: @SylorHuang yeah,it will get the same error,you need to replace them in your server side,in other words,you need to replace it in your ruby code when you generate the value for `comment.content`

Comment: OK, I will try it ,Thanks.